# NHibernate JoinQueryOver and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a query

```
var query = _session.QueryOver<TEntity>().JoinQueryOver<PropertyMultTable>(p => p.Properties).Where(propertyPredicate).List();
```

this query generates the next SQL

```
 select this_.BaseEntity_id as BaseId0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Label as Label0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Description as Descript3_0_1_ ,
        this_1_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_0_1_ ,
        this_.Width as Width2_1_ ,
        this_.Height as Height2_1_ ,
        this_.Duration as Duration2_1_ ,
        propertymu1_.id as id4_0_ ,
        propertymu1_.Name as Name4_0_ ,
        propertymu1_1_.DateTimeValue as DateTime2_5_0_ ,
        propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue as IntegerV2_6_0_ ,
        propertymu1_3_.DecimalValue as DecimalV2_7_0_ ,
        propertymu1_4_.StringValue as StringVa2_8_0_
 from   [Video] this_
        inner join [BaseEntity] this_1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = this_1_.BaseId
        inner join [PropertyMultTable] propertymu1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = propertymu1_.BaseEntity_id
        left outer join DateTimeValues propertymu1_1_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_1_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join IntegerValues propertymu1_2_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_2_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join DecimalValues propertymu1_3_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_3_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join StringValues propertymu1_4_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_4_.PropertyMultTable_id
 where  ( propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue >= 459144
          and propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue <= 691982
        )
```

but I want to get only the Entity, without the properties. So, I need SQL like this:

```
 select this_.BaseEntity_id as BaseId0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Label as Label0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Description as Descript3_0_1_ ,
        this_1_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_0_1_ ,
        this_.Width as Width2_1_ ,
        this_.Height as Height2_1_ ,
        this_.Duration as Duration2_1_
 from   [Video] this_
        inner join [BaseEntity] this_1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = this_1_.BaseId
        inner join [PropertyMultTable] propertymu1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = propertymu1_.BaseEntity_id
        left outer join DateTimeValues propertymu1_1_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_1_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join IntegerValues propertymu1_2_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_2_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join DecimalValues propertymu1_3_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_3_.PropertyMultTable_id
        left outer join StringValues propertymu1_4_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_4_.PropertyMultTable_id
 where  ( propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue >= 459144
          and propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue <= 691982
        )
```

or, even much better, like this:

```
    select distinct this_.BaseEntity_id as BaseId0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Label as Label0_1_ ,
        this_1_.Description as Descript3_0_1_ ,
        this_1_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_0_1_ ,
        this_.Width as Width2_1_ ,
        this_.Height as Height2_1_ ,
        this_.Duration as Duration2_1_
 from   [Video] this_
        inner join [BaseEntity] this_1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = this_1_.BaseId
        inner join [PropertyMultTable] propertymu1_ on this_.BaseEntity_id = propertymu1_.BaseEntity_id
        left outer join IntegerValues propertymu1_2_ on propertymu1_.id = propertymu1_2_.PropertyMultTable_id
 where  ( propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue >= 459144
          and propertymu1_2_.IntegerValue <= 691982
        )
```

Can I do this with Fluent NHibernate? Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Can you append the class declaration of Video?

Comment: The Video is the class with 3 properties Width, Height and Duration, and it is derived from the BaseEntity which contains only the properties: Id, Label, Description and CreatedDate

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is used to create the mappings, not to make the queries.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it using HQL.

```
var hqlQuery=string.Format( "select v from Video as v inner join v.BaseEntity 
as be inner join v.PropertyMultTable as pmt left outer join pmt.IntegerValues 
as iv where be.BaseEntity_id=v.BaseId and be.BaseEntity_id=pmt.BaseEntity_id and 
pmt.Id=iv.PropertyMultTable_id and iv.IntegerValue >={0} and iv.IntegerValue
<={1}", 459144,691982);
```

note here when inner join is done Im assuming the property names are the same as mentioned in the query above. they should be the exact same thing as mentione din your property or you will get an nhibernate exception.

If it doesnt work post the entire class diagram.

you can run this query as follows:

```
session.CreateQuery(hqlquery).List<Video>();
```

Comment: this is not the solution for my goal. I don't need HQL, becouse I have generic repository, wich can take as TEntity a diferent classes, like Image or Document.

Comment: Then you should probably consider Criteria queries. I can help you out if you provide me the class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `Future()`:

```
var query =
  _session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
    .JoinQueryOver<PropertyMultTable>(p => p.Properties)
    .Future()
    .Where(propertyPredicate).List();
```